# How to change a dropdown into a table format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have fetch data through ajax from my database in dropdown format.

now I want to change the dropdown list into table. I am very beginner to ajax... I have done this with many of my efforts, but to convert it into table is looking the most difficult task to me.

Below is my complete code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function select_std(){
  var ali=$('#class_std').val();
  $('#std_name').html('');
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url().'admin/test/'?>"+ali,
    type:"GET",
    success:function(res){
      $('#std_name').append(res);
    }
  });
}

</script>
```

This is my controller

```
public function test($id=''){
  $table='students';
  $columns=array('*');
  $where=array('c_id'=>$id);
  $data['rcd']= $this->Crud->get_records($table, $columns, $where)->result();

  foreach ($data['rcd'] as $value) {
    $output = "<option value='".$value->std_id."'>".$value->Name."</option>";
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <select id="class_std" name="c_id" class="form-control selectboxit" onchange="select_std()">

    <?php 
    $classes = $this->db->get('classes')->result_array();
    foreach($classes as $row):
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['c_id'];?>">
      <?php echo $row['C_NAME'];?>
    </option>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here my database is displaying

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <select id="std_name" class="form-control">

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure that you want? You can use dummy data / placeholders for the changeable items. It is difficult to help you if we don't know what your end goal looks like.

Comment: My dear Sean, my final target is to show all the students in table as i click particular class from dropdown..

Comment: Great, then show an example of what that looks like. We can help guide you on that path to understanding the code, but not be expected to just provide it.

Comment: currently, when user click on class dropdown all the student's are showing in dropdown list..for this i do this $output = "<option value='".$value->std_id."'>".$value->Name."</option>";
              echo $output;

Comment: i want to delete the dropdown and show in a table concept should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the complaints above, but despite all the shortcomings in the question, see if this rocks your boat:

```js
/* JS */
function select_std(){
  var ali=$('#class_std').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url().'admin/test/'?>"+ali,
    type:"GET",
    success:function(res){
      $('#myTable tbody').append(res);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<?php
/* YOUR CONTROLLER - replace your old one with this one */
public function test($id=''){
  $table='students';
  $columns=array('*');
  $where=array('c_id'=>$id);
  $data['rcd']= $this->Crud->get_records($table, $columns, $where)->result();

  foreach ($data['rcd'] as $value) {
    $output = "<tr><td>".$value->std_id."</td><td>".$value->Name."</td></tr>";
    echo $output;
  }
}
?>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <select id="class_std" name="c_id" class="form-control selectboxit" onchange="select_std()">

    <?php 
    $classes = $this->db->get('classes')->result_array();
    foreach($classes as $row):
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['c_id'];?>">
      <?php echo $row['C_NAME'];?>
    </option>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
      <table id="myTable">
          <thead>
              <th>Student ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: very much thankful Mr.Aydin.. wish you best of luck!

Comment: Did it work? If it did, you may accept it as the correct answer and also, click the up arrow. This is how things work around here :)

Comment: another question from you if you don't mind! i have display all the student's name as per your kind recommendation. now i want to associate input form field with each student so that i can insert his marks in the databse?? How can i this..

Comment: wii be waiting for you

Comment: For that I would need to see your DB structure, methods that write to the DB, etc. It is an elaborate exercise. You can follow, for example, this post (http://phppot.com/demo/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/) to achieve it. Then, if you have questions along the way, you can ask them here in SO.